# Dynatables and Tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltipster, dynatable

I have a table that has a column with tooltips in it. W/out dynatables, it works. But, when I apply dynatables to it, the tooltips are not shown anymore.

Here is my JS:

```
var initTooltips = function(){
    $('.tt').tooltipster({
        animation: 'fade',
        delay: 200,
        theme: ['tooltipster-punk', 'tooltipster-ls'],
        contentAsHTML: true
    });
    alert("INIT");
};

var $statsTable = $('#stats-table');
if ($statsTable.length) {
    $statsTable.dynatable({}).bind('dynatable:afterProcess', initTooltips);
    initTooltips();
}
```

The `INIT` gets fired AND the `tooltipstered` class gets applied to the according element, but it does not show the actual tooltip on hover. I am not sure, how to debug this and what the cause may be. Nothing happens in Firebug on hover either.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't know Dynatable but it must edit the DOM and the data attached to elements is lost. Try initiliazing tooltips only after Dynatable is done doing its job.

Comment: Well, don't I do that with `dynatable:afterProcess`? The `initTooltips` function initializes the tooltips. The do get applied to the elements but not shonw on hover...

Comment: Dynatable may be initialized asynchronously, try to remove `initTooltips();`